# Target class [DataController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-8

Hi so i'm making simple crud API but somehow when i check the route i keep showing Target class [DataController] does not exist

and this is my controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\DataController;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Data;

class DataController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return Data::all();
    }
}
```

and this my route:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::get('data','DataController@index');
Route::post('data','DataController@create');
Route::put('/data/{id}','DataController@update');
Route::delete('/data/{id}','DataController@delete');
```

I'm pretty new learn about API in Laravel and i saw use php artisan config:cache and composer auto-load don't work as well so maybe something  wrong in my code or what?

Comment: this is a change in Laravel 8 and how it handles your routes to controllers. It no longer prefixes any namespace to the controller to resolve it  .... i marked this as a duplicate as all questions like this are the same issue

Comment: remove DataController from the namespace. namespace should only contain the path to file, not the file name

Comment: yes that too as Faramarz has stated (most likely) though you could have that in that namespace if you like

Comment: i read the documentation and it's different how to route in laravel 8 thx for your answer m8

Comment: no problem, good luck and have fun with Laravel